# Testing PHP on Ubuntu with Apache2 and PHP7

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have installed `Apache2` and `PHP 7`  with`(sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt)` on my machine. When I hit `php -v` in terminal, it return:

> PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP
>   Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

So then I created one `PHP` file at `var/www/html/e.php` with the below content:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the browser (http://localhost/e.php), it does not show the php variable, just works the html tag. What am I missing? The Ubuntu "It Works" page of Apache works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you see the PHP code on the page or something else?

Comment: It doesnt show anything regarding php, looks like there is no php on my machine. @JuliePelletier

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7

Comment: @JulinhodaAdelaide any update for us !!

Answer (score 1):

you have to install apache+php module.

find the below command to install all php module with apache

```
apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-curl php7.0-gmp php7.0-mbstring php7.0-phpdbg php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-dba php7.0-imap php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-pspell php7.0-sybase php7.0-bz2 php7.0-dev php7.0-interbase php7.0-mysql php7.0-readline php7.0-tidy php7.0-cgi php7.0-enchant php7.0-intl php7.0-odbc php7.0-recode php7.0-xml php7.0-cli php7.0-fpm php7.0-json php7.0-opcache php7.0-snmp php7.0-xmlrpc php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-ldap php7.0-pgsql php7.0-soap php7.0-xsl php7.0-mongo
```

then run the next command

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```

then assigen the mode of php handler

```
a2enmod php7.0
```

restart the apache webserver

```
service apache2 restart
```

then try to open into browser .
http://localhost/e.php)

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same issue before in ubuntu ,try to move that file from `var/www/html/e.php` to `/opt/lampp/htdocs` and make sure it had the right "-rw-r--r--"

Comment: Have you followed any tutorial? Can you share? I dont neither have the folder lampp.
Thanks

Comment: so you don't have apache in your local machine

Comment: When I get to localhost, it does show the "It works" page of Ubuntu PHP... @Pacman

Comment: did you install php with xampp or install every component alone php and apache ??

Comment: I installed each part alone, I guess maybe i'm missing something..?!

Comment: well this is not a recommended way for developping php application even if it works you'll still need some server extension i suggest you to install the xampp package it contains the latest php version with apache and some great tools for developping here is the link https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html you'll get a file with ".sh" extension go to terminal and run it and it will do all the thing for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PHP apache2 module to work with PHP. You can install libapache2-mod-php from your terminal by typing the command

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

Apache will be restarted automatically and PHP then available.